# How to replace a class?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am writing test files for a Python module

```
class A:
    def func(self):
        B().sub_func()
class B:
    def sub_func(self):
        pass
```

and I need block B's side effect while testing A.
my question is that how to replace class B in test file.

```
class ATest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        a=A()
        a.func()
        #now object a will invoke a func that B is a mock class
```

following the instruction of accepted answer. I finish my tests

tws/main.py

```
class A(object):
    def func(self):
        b=B()
        print('func ')
        b.sub_func()
class B(object):
    def sub_func(self):
        print('real sub')
        c=C()
        c.c_sub_func()
class C(object):
    def c_sub_func(self):
        print('c')
```

test/test_mock.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from tws.main import A
class B():
    def sub_func(self):
        print('mock')
        return 12
class TestMock(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('tws.main.B',new=B)
    def test_af(self):
        a=A()
        print(a.__dict__)
        a.func()
        print('rrr')
```

it will print mock,hope it will help other people with same problems.

Comment: If you want to mock in unittest, have you looked at [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)? But note that your design is not very testable - having `a` build its own instance of `B` introduces a lot of coupling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can mock out class B by using `unittest.mock` - in particular [`patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers).

You can use `patch()` as a decorator on your test method, making sure you add an extra argument to receive the mocked class B:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class ATest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('package.module.B')
    def test_a(self, mock_b):  # mock_b will hold the mocked class B
        a = A()
        a.func()
```

Note that the path you pass to the decorator must be the path to where B is *used* (the same module containing class A) *not* the path to where class B is defined. See [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) for more info on that.

Comment: great! let me have a try.